# grails elastic search data binding error

Tags: data-binding, grails

I'm using grails 2.0.0 M1 with elastic search plugin 0.18.7.1-SNAPSHOT.

I can install this, and can see it running ok using the default configuration.  I can also see my domain objects being created and successfully added to the index from my DBBootStrap.groovy file.

However...

When trying to create only (not save) a domain object from the web layer (after the Bootstap script has successfully run) I get the following error:

```
def testco = new Company(name:"test");

Line | Method
->>  13 | registerCustomEditors in     org.grails.plugins.elasticsearch.conversion.CustomEditorRegistar
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    38 | test                  in com.tempism.company.CompanyController
|   886 | runTask . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run                   in     ''
^   619 | run . . . . . . . . . in java.lang.Thread
```

Further investigation reveals a stack trace with the relevant piece being ...

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.addToAllMethodsIfPublic(MetaClassImpl.java:2975)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.addProperties(MetaClassImpl.java:2954)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.initialize(MetaClassImpl.java:2918)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.initialize(ExpandoMetaClass.java:468)
    at     org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClassUnderLock(ClassInfo.java:166)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClass(ClassInfo.java:182)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.getMetaClass(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:242)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getMetaClass(InvokerHelper.java:751)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.createCallConstructorSite(CallSiteArray.java:71)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:54)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:190)
    at org.grails.plugins.elasticsearch.conversion.CustomEditorRegistar.registerCustomEditors(CustomEditorRegistar.groovy:13)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.binding.GrailsDataBinder.registerCustomEditors(GrailsDataBinder.java:182)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.binding.GrailsDataBinder.registerCustomEditors(GrailsDataBinder.java:263)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.binding.GrailsDataBinder.createBinder(GrailsDataBinder.java:287)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.binding.DataBindingUtils.createDataBinder(DataBindingUtils.java:238)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.binding.DataBindingUtils.bindObjectToDomainInstance(DataBindingUtils.java:169)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.binding.DataBindingUtils.bindObjectToDomainInstance(DataBindingUtils.java:112)
    at     org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.api.ControllersDomainBindingApi.initialize(ControllersDomainBindingApi.java:57)
    at com.tempism.company.Company.<init>(Company.groovy)
```

Being relatively new at grails, I have NO idea how creating of domain objects/DataBinding could work in the DBBootStrap context, but NOT in any other context (Service/Controller.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

cheers.

UPDATE...

```
//works
def co =  new Company();
co.name = "hello"
co.save();

//doesn't work
new Company(name:"hello2").save();
```

Comment: weirdly instantiating the new object, updating the properties works, then saving works. But instantiating it with parameters doesn't...

Answer (score 0):

resolved by updating to grails 2.0.1